# How do I find out if My activity was started by an Activity of my own app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a library project that displays pdfs. My main project has a few PDFs that I want to display. So I use it. Also, I have added intent filters for the activity that displays the pdf(so that other apps can also use it to display pdfs).

I want to detect if my PDFVIEWER was started by my own activity or not(I want to display the Title Bar if its started externally) how do I do that?

Here is my activity declaration:

```
  <activity
                android:name="com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument"/>
                    <data android:mimeType="application/xps"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                    <data android:mimeType="application/pdf"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                    <data android:mimeType="application/x-cbz"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                    <data android:scheme="file"/>
                    <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
                    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xps"/>
                    <data android:host="*"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                    <data android:scheme="file"/>
                    <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
                    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf"/>
                    <data android:host="*"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                    <data android:scheme="file"/>
                    <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
                    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.cbz"/>
                    <data android:host="*"/>
                </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: could you please tell me which library are you using to open a pdf or could please share your library code. I have a situation that i can not use other app to open pdf. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am using the mupdf library. what are your issues?

Comment: @harvey_sash please share the link

Comment: http://www.mupdf.com/docs/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you, if it's possible to get the activity which started the intent, but as a workaround you can put a Boolean value in your Intent to make sure your PDFViewer was started by your app.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(fileUri);
    intent.putExtra("myAppStarted", true);
```

And in your started activity:

```
    boolean displayTitleBar = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("myAppStarted", false);
```

Please note it is recommended to use static final String variable with "myAppStarted" instead of hardcoding the String in different places.

Comment: I had not expected this. This is not really a solution. I want something that tells me which activity/package opened my activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use getCallingActivity, provided your activity was started using startActivityForResult. A better solution would be to add extra information into your intent that tells you if the calling activity is yours.

Answer (score 0):

`AppCompat.getReferrer()` should return the package name of the `Activity` that started yours.